# [APEX][File System] Save and Read KML files with APEX

Tags: apex, file-storage, fileupload

I am new to Salesforce and Apex.I have a requirement of uploading a KML file to Salesforce and save it in a Workspace named 'My Files'. Then I should be able to list down filenames of 'My Files' Workspace and read the content of specific file.

1. Can I call a method in a APEXController from UI to send KML file and save it on the server in 'My Files' workspace?
2. How can I read files on 'My Files' workspace with Apex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requirement is not well phrased. You should go back to the person that gave it to you and request clarification.

Salesforce does not have a file system as such. There are several sObjects commonly used to store file data, including [`Document`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_document.htm), [`Attachment`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm), and [`ContentVersion`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm). `Document` and `ContentVersion` both have notions of a folder (or library), but work very differently.

Additionally, file upload mechanisms in the UI are completely different based on whether you're using [Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputFile.htm) or [Lightning](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/documentation).

Get clarity on the requirement and make an initial stab at an implementation. Trailhead is a good place to start on implementation specifics. Salesforce Stack Exchange can provide more support with problems during implementation.